# code for finding position of chosen letter (by user) in a sentence that the user inputs

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, position

I have spent hours trying to figure out how to write this code, but it won't work. It was running for specific letters, but now the opening two prompts aren't even showing up.  The assignment is to prompt user to write a sentence, then for them to choose a letter, and then to write a program that displays the positions of the chosen letter.
here is my code:

```
if (exercise.equals("4c") || exercise.equals("0")){
            System.out.println("(problem 4c) Character Location");
            System.out.println("Enter a line of text: ");
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            String lineOfText = reader.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Specify a character to be found: ");
            Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
            String theLetter = choice.nextLine();

            char x = theLetter.charAt(0);  

            for (int z = 0; z < lineOfText.length(); z++)              
                if (lineOfText.charAt(z) == 'x')                      
                    System.out.println(z);`
```

`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably related to this part of the code `if (lineOfText.charAt(z) == 'x')`. I think you meant for that `'x'` to actually be the variable `x` and not the character.

As for the prompts not showing up that's probably related to whatever you have around this code that's creating the `exercise` variable.

Comment: Thank you so much!! changing the 'x' to just x fixed that problem, but I still don't really know what to do about the exercise variable